# place an element after another element in the same div

Tags: jquery

I have the following html:

```
<div class="nbhds-overlay active" style="display: block;">

    <h3 class="h31 allnbhds"><a href="#">All Neighborhoods</a></h3>

    <h3 class="h32"><a data-id="51Cameo" href="#">one</a></h3>
    <h3 class="h33"><a href="#" class="active">two</a></h3>
    <h3 class="h34"><a href="#">three</a></h3>
    <h3 class="h35"><a href="#">four</a></h3>
    <h3 class="h36"><a href="#">five</a><h3>

</div>
```

I want to place the `h3` element that contains `a.active` after the `h3.allnbhds` h3.

Tried like so but it isn't working, any ideas?

```
if ( $('.nbhds-overlay a.active').length ) {
        $(this).parent().insertAfter($(this).parent().parent().find('h3.allnbhds'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign that `<h3>` to a variable and insert that variable after 'h3.allnbhds'

```
var activeHead = $('h3').find('a.active').parent('h3');
activeHead.insertAfter($('.nbhds-overlay').find('h3.allnbhds'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this just as fast without jQuery

```
var active = document.querySelector('h3 > a.active').parentNode;
var allnbhds = document.querySelector('.allnbhds');

allnbhds.parentNode.insertBefore(active, allnbhds.nextElementSibling);
```